# How to retrieve value from sql query in c# OnDeleted event

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve returned value from SQL after deleted with SqlDataSource
OnDeleted event.

```
protected void OnDeletedLeadACRule(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
     e.[some code to retrieve the value selected from SQL]
}
```

In normal case for example you can read the returned value like that :

```
DataSet ds = DBcon.db.ExecuteDataSet("GetMachines");
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

Comment: whats ur delete query? whats the return you expect?

Comment: any returned value from sql to c# is a dataset or datatable. so that what i accept to get. the query it doesn't matter. for example the query is "SELECT 2" i want get the value 2 .

Comment: excuse me? you are performing a select on the `OnDeleted` event? I am sorry, i am clueless here

Comment: when you execute a query you not all the time want to delete even if it is on delete command. before i'm deleting i have to make sure few things before i perform delete command . and SELECT is the return value to point if the deleted success or not . i guess you are clueless here because you don't experience with SQL. not all the query is one row. and if it so make you clueless you can consider that question with SelectCommand it doesn't matter to the answer.